# Finding n using differential mass balance

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I have tried solving it through basic material balance equation. I know its not a pure mathematics question, but the question just involves applying differential mass balance in 3 dimension. I am comfortable with 1-D but I'm stuck in case of three variables. It would be great if you could tell me the differential balance equation (In - Out = Accumulation) for this case. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know what the mass balance equation is? Your question is looking at the _diffusion_ case where the resulting partial differential equation is just a heat equation. So all the question is asking you to do is to (1) write down the correct heat equation [by looking it up in your textbook] and (2) plug the function $C$ into it and taking the derivatives and (3) find the value $n$ such that the left hand side equals the right.

Comment: The equation that $C$ must satisfy is $$\frac{\partial C(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t} = K\left[\frac{\partial^2 C(x,y,z,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 C(x,y,z,t)}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2 C(x,y,z,t)}{\partial z^2}\right]$$

Comment: Oh! I noticed it now. Indeed I got n through this equation. Thanks